# Tag cleanup request: [24hour]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

From the [24hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/24hour) tag wiki:

> 24hour is a term meaning "all day" or "continuous". It is based on the fact that there are 24 hours in a day.

I don't think the tag serves a useful purpose. Questions tagged with it seem to relate to things like time formats, doing things every 24 hours, etc.

Comment: I think the tag description is off. People seem to be using it when their question is about 24 hour clock formats (as opposed to the standard 12 hour clock). I still don't know if that's a useful tag.

Comment: There is [tag:hour] too.

Comment: Also [nanotime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nanotime) and [milliseconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/milliseconds)

Comment: @BilltheLizard they want their question answered in 24 hours, obviously.

Comment: @Braiam I thought that's what the `[urgent]` tag is for. :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard I hope that tag won't be abused anytime soon.

Comment: They want their question answered by [Chloe O'Brian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloe_O'Brian).

Comment: Do I tag status complected?

Comment: `[status-complected]` --> exit message for a tanning booth?

Comment: One can never be an expert in `time`.

Comment: Hey, I'm an expert in `[24hours]`. I have 36 years experience with it - every day of my life.

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio Since `O'Brian is exceptionally intelligent and displays extraordinary mastery of computer science` she'll defiinitly get the job done in 24h ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For most people outside of the US, [24hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/24hour) time is just [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time).

So, I went through the [24hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/24hour) tag and retagged most of its questions: some just needed [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time), some needed a combination of [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time) and [datetime-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime-format), and some *didn't need the tag at all*. In fact, for many of the posts, the tag wasn't relevant and didn't add any crucial information to the question.

I burninated [military-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/military-time) and left questions that adhere to the [24hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/24hour) time wiki tagged with [24hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/24hour) because I feel that its current definition **does** add information to the question.

---

It appears that all of the questions that I left in [24hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/24hour) are gone: I'm not sure where they've been retagged to (if they've been retagged at all - the tag may have just been removed from the posts altogether).

Comment: I cant see any 24hour questions though.

Comment: @nishantjr Someone else must have retagged them. It looks like they've been moved to [tag:continuous] (which I'm not sure is the right choice).

Comment: Why did you burinate military-time without any burination request or community concensus!!

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion It only had three questions, and it wasn't relevant to any of them. People [also didn't seem to like it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268776/3366929) (10k only).

Comment: @AstroCB That makes no sense. According to the wiki [tag:continuous] is for continuous functions.

Comment: @nishantjr Exactly: I didn't do it, so I can't tell you why, though. I'd wait for whoever did it to post here.

Comment: @nishantjr [Sam](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/227577/sam) points out that there has been no activity in [tag:continuous] for a while, so the [tag:24hour] tag may have just been outright removed, which I'm also not sure is the right choice.

Answer (score 9):

I believe what has happened here was completely wrong.

The original description for [24hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/24hour) was,

> Use this tag for questions related to continuously running programs or systems.

Which I think is completely misleading.

If you are writing a question about continuously running programs then surely [continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous) would make more sense?

Retagging to [military-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/military-time) was the wrong thing to do as it is very US-centric. [24hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/24hour) makes much more sense for this.

What should have happened in my opinion was that the [24hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/24hour) description be changed to something along the lines to:

> Use this tag for questions specific to the 24 hour time format

And questions about continuous programming be retagged as [continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuous).

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the purpose of tags. I assumed tags were to help people intereted in certain topics to favorite them, or to search using tags. I'm not sure someone would search using tags like 'continuous' or '24hour'. What exactly is the purpose of tags?

Comment: @nishantjr It may very well be the case that this tag should be burninated as it's not a good fit. My concern is that what has happened is that it's just been retagged to something even less clear.

Comment: @dav_i I retagged it as a separate measure and I should have been more internationally conscious when I did so. However, the only reason I did it was to put all of the questions referring to this concept under one tag *that already exists* (i.e. [tag:military-time]). I don't think that the tag adds much information in the first place, which is why I waited to see what others thought of the tag before doing anything more drastic.

Comment: You burinated military-time without concensus, now that is drastic @astroCB

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I'm not so sure with three questions. What's more drastic is that **someone else burninated [tag:24hour] without posting here**, on the *actual post requesting that it be **retagged***.

Comment: [tag:continuous] is _terrible_. What a useless tag.

Comment: Why is `military-time` US centric?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff: Because only people from certain generations in the US think of 24-hour time format as "military time". For much of the world, it's just the standard time format, or even if not, it's not particularly associated with military.